# Change Dask worker ttl for a running cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm running a dask cluster and some of my computations are long enough to trigger the default worker ttl of 5 minutes or 300 seconds. I tried changing the config value of `distributed.scheduler.worker-ttl` on the scheduler:

```py
def set_config_worker_ttl():
    dask.config.set({'distributed.scheduler.worker-ttl': '30 seconds'})
client.run_on_scheduler(set_config_worker_ttl)

def get_config_worker_ttl():
    return dask.config.get('distributed.scheduler.worker-ttl')
client.run_on_scheduler(get_config_worker_ttl)
>>> "30 seconds"
```

(I tried 30 seconds as it is easier to test, in practice I would want to set it to something larger than 5 minutes.)

However I tried testing this by sending an expensive computation to a worker, and in the logs I see it still uses the default 5 minute timeout:

```
2023-07-25 06:20:59,346 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove worker <WorkerState 'tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx', name: xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx, status: closed, memory: 0, processing: 0>
2023-07-25 06:20:59,346 - distributed.scheduler - WARNING - Worker failed to heartbeat within 300 seconds. Closing: <WorkerState 'tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx', name: xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx, status: closed, memory: 0, processing: 0>
```

I'm a bit confused why it says 'processing: 0', but this is the worker that was running my blocking task, and the task switched to 'no-worker' in the dashboard.

How can I change the worker-ttl of a cluster that is already running a scheduler (and workers)? Emphasis here is on 'already running', due to restrictions in the environment I'm running I would really like to avoid doing this through a environment flag or global config.

Comment: How about [`Client.run(function, *args[, workers, wait, ...])Run a function on all workers outside of task scheduling system`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html?highlight=Client.run#api) but as this states [Often we want to run custom code when we start up or tear down a scheduler or worker. We might do this manually with functions like Client.run or Client.run_on_scheduler, but this is error prone and difficult to automate.](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/how-to/customize-initialization.html)

Comment: `client.run` runs the function on the workers, but this is a scheduler setting

Comment: Which Dask cluster deployment method are you using? You need to set the property before the worker is started.